# Drupal 7 local install faliure

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, xampp

Doing my very first loading of local Drupal 7 with Xampp and install went well. In Windows 7 tried to open localhost in browser and received this error message:

> Warning: require_once(C:\xampp\htdocs\drupal/includes/bootstrap.inc):
>   failed to open stream: No such file or directory in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\drupal\index.php on line 19
>
> Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required
>   'C:\xampp\htdocs\drupal/includes/bootstrap.inc'
>   (include_path='.;C:\xampp\php\PEAR') in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\drupal\index.php on line 19

This was a stock standard install until this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure that you have the file named `bootstrap.inc` inside `includes` folder.

Comment: Oh... The install didn't come with an includes folder or a bootstrap.inc file. Suggestions? Should I download another and start again? Thx!

Comment: Yayyyy! Reinstalled Drupal - found 'includes' - found bootstrap.inc and it works!! THANKS. Now on to the hard stuff!